# $dialogs.create brings up a popup form on my website but the code that defines the pop up has formatting constraints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So in my website's source code, when a button is pressed a function runs in it's controller. This is the function that runs on the button press:

```
$scope.launch = function(idOfSpotOfInterest, schedOfSpotOfInterest){
    var dlg = null; 


    dlg = $dialogs.create('/dialogs/whatsyourname2.html','whatsYourNameCtrl2',{schlong: idOfSpotOfInterest, schedOfSpot:schedOfSpotOfInterest},{key: false,back: 'static'});


};
```

It seems the parameter '/dialogs/whatsyourname2.html' is a reference to where the modal's source code is, while the parameter 'whatsYourNameCtrl2' is a reference to the controller that corresponds with the modal.

Later on in my code i have the following that seems to define the modal:

```
.run(['$templateCache',function($templateCache){
 $templateCache.put('/dialogs/whatsyourname2.html', *source code for modal*);
```

Where *source code for modal* has my html that describes what the modal contains and how it looks. The problem is my source code for the modal seems to have to be in block format without line breaks or indentation, which makes it almost impossible to decipher and edit. At this point it's a lot of code and the process of tweaking it takes forever as I have to stare at a wall of text. If i try and break the lines up the website just doesn't build. Sublime text editor seems to be treating the entire source code for the modal as one giant line as required for it to work, which confuses me.

Thoughts on how to fix this?! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming you are using [Angular Dialog Service](https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service)

You are using the minified version of it.

```html
<script src="dialogs.min.js"></script>

Change to this
<script src="dialogs.js"></script>
```

that should give you the actual code